# Can an infinite regular language be decomposed in this way?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, kleene-star

If $A$ is an infinite regular language, can there exist a finite regular language $B$ such that $A = BB^*$?

Comment: If $A$ contains the empty string, in almost every case the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to clarify what is being asked: do you mean can **every** infinite regular language be decomposed in this way, or is it **possible that some** infinite regular language can be decomposed in this way? Your question does not make this clear.

- For the first version of the question, try considering the following language: $b \cup a^*$. Can this be decomposed in this way? How could you prove it?
- For the second version of the question, try considering the following language: $a^*$. Can this be decomposed in this way? How could you prove it?